# Issue with React TypeScript - Canvas Animation and onMouseMove Conflict

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, onmousemove

I'm relatively new to React and TypeScript and have run into a problem when trying to create a simple animation for a rectangle within a `canvas`, along with including the `onMouseMove` event for another rectangle. It seems that these two functionalities somehow conflict with each other, and I'm struggling to find a solution.

**Problem:**
I am trying to create a simple React component that displays a `canvas` with a moving rectangle. Additionally, I want to capture mouse movement in another rectangle using the `onMouseMove` event. However, the interaction between the animation of the `canvas` and the `onMouseMove` event does not work as expected.

I have prepared a [code example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-x3l8pq?file=%2Fsrc%2FCanvas.tsx%3A39%2C18).

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to resolve this conflicte. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: "does not work as expected." What is expected here? How do intended the two rectangles to move?

Comment: I want one rectangle to perform a left-right animation, while the other rectangle follows my mouse pointer to the left and right. At the moment, the two are influencing each other.